# Prevent my random word ticker from making my sentence jump around?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple word ticker as part of a sentence, the ticker sits beside the word `to`. At the moment as the city name changes its width makes the `to` jump around, I'm wondering how I could make this to remain fixed no matter what size the city name becomes, I don't really want to set a width on the city name either but not sure of an alternative.

Example HTML is

```
<h1>We are going<br>to <span class="ticker js-ticker"></span></h1>
```

Codepen is http://codepen.io/styler/pen/oXjwqp

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible if you want to keep this line centered. How do you expect to have `to` fixed and yet the whole line centered? What should the `to` be fixed to?

You can either adjust the line to the left, or you could add a little `margin-left` so it looks as if it's centered. But it will almost always look off-centered, especially for longer city names.

Answer (score 0):

First option that you have is to use [monospaced fonts](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/monospaced), which have a fixed width for each letter. So as long as you have a fixed amount of letters, you will have the same width.

Second option is to have a pre-determined width for the city name, maybe with a surrounding box to justify the fixed width. I've made a working [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNoZgX) of what it could look like.

```
.ticker {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #444444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;


    span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Third option, like Darek Kay said, is to not have the text centered.

This is more of a design question than it is a programming question though. There's no definitive answer to this, it's only based on your preferences.

Comment: Yeah totally understand, monospace would be the ticket actually for this but I'm dealing with designers so that's a hard sell. Thanks!